# При копировании кода из Visual Studio 2022 17.9.5 в Word не сохраняется форматирование

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

До переустановки Windows такой проблемы не возникало, любой код из VS копировался и форматировался в Word без проблем. Возможно ли что проблема с последней версией Visual Studio? Либо проблема в моих настройках?

Comment: В ворде попробуйте опцию "Вставить как" и разные варианты. Проблема точно не в студии.

Comment: @aepot Если вы про 3 варианта форматирования после вставки в ворде , то там все 3 из них вставляют код без цвета, но с изменением шрифта у каждого

Comment: Тогда сдаюсь, надо искать.

Comment: @aepot Несколько дней мучаюсь с этой проблемой, я уже пробовал версии обеих продуктов менять и пробовать разные, но все тщетно. Все еще думаю что есть решение в изменении какой либо настройки которую я никак не могу найти

Comment: Вот что нашёл https://stackoverflow.com/q/55209429/12888024 там про галочку есть в студии

Comment: @aepot Да, про настройку с "копировать форматированный текст" в VS, я уже пробовал и ставить и убирать, но тоже без изменений. В этом вопросе также писали про расширение Productivity Power Tools, которое делает из скопированного кода , HTML код, но даже так у меня вставляется просто белый код на черном фоне ;(

Comment: Ну вы по очереди пробуйте перезапуская студию.

Comment: на [фото](https://i.imgur.com/WxTC0JW.png) показал форматирование при: 
1. Вставка с установленным расширением и включеной галкочкой форматированием текста при копировании
2. Вставка без галочки в настройках
3. Вставка с включенной галочкой(Поменялся только шрифт)